# GMSMapView compass button not visible

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google maps ask for iOS app using swift. I have added map(GMSMapView) in story board and trying to compass button like this

```
mapView.settings.compassButton = true
```

But i am unable to see the compass button.

Comment: Got solution, it is displaying when map is not in the north direction . If map is in north direction it is not displaying

Answer (score 3):

If the navigation bar is visible, the compass button is behind it. To make it appear below the navigation bar you need to add a padding to the top side of the map view.

**Objective-C**

```
UIEdgeInsets mapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(80.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
GMSMapView *mapView;
mapView.padding = mapInsets;
```

**Swift**

```
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
mapView.padding = mapInsets
```

Comment: This only happens sometimes for me, any idea why? I have one view controller where the compass is below the navigation bar, and another where it's not.

Comment: @ArielSD, I can't really say. Is there any constraint added to the map miew?

Comment: Thanks for the response - on one view, I was accounting for a navigation bar, on another, I wasn't - it was behind the bar the whole time. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks for checking. I just moved the GMSMapView to just under the navigation bar.